# Why Impala spend a lot of time Opening HDFS File (TotalRawHdfsOpenFileTime)?

Tags: hdfs, olap, impala, namenode

I find that my Impala swarm performs not stable, normally it takes only a few seconds (less than 10s) to finish a query, but occasionally it will take more than 40s (and this situation will last for a few minutes), and when that happens, accroding to the profile, TotalRawHdfsOpenFileTime is very high, which implies most of the time is spend on opening HDFS file.

So what is the possible reason and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is time spent opening files. If you're querying HDFS, this often means that it's spending time fetching data from the namenode.

We saw dramatic improvements in a lot of production deployments running into this bottleneck by enabling file handle caching  - https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/impala_scalability.html#scalability_file_handle_cache

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please tell me more details about how to diagnose the open file procedure?   I have asked the SA of HDFS NameNode and he found nothing unusual in the server side log, is there any detailed logs in the Impala side (client of NN) ?

Comment: TotalRawHdfsOpenFileTime is telling us that it's spending a lot of time opening the files. CachedFileHandlesMissCount will tell you how many times a file had to be opened. A single file can be opened multiple times depending on num of columns, etc.

We've seen this when there are there are many files in the table, many columns, or if there is some slowness in doing NN RPCs (could be network, namenode performance, or something like acquiring Kerberos tickets to connect to the NN).